# Unable to migrate a google cloud project into a new organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have followed the directions for migrating a project that I own into an organization for which I have the 3 required privileges Stated in this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing.

When going into to do the migration, the organization is still not showing. Is there any other thing I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

After reading the description I understood that the project that you want to migrate is currently under an existing organization. If so, GCP will need to first remove the project from the existing organization node. In order to do that I will recommend you to open [public issue in this tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui). Bear in mind that you will be requested a valid reason for this procedure.

Once this is done from our side, you will then be able to add it to the new organization yourself following [this article](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing). In order to do that the user must need to be:

- An Owner or Editor of the Project, AND
- A Project Creator in the destination Organization